# How to dynamically get mouse position within an element

Tags: jquery, html, css

This is my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/KLY3X/1/) :

## HTML

```
<div id="myDiv">
    Hello
</div>​
```

## CSS

```
#myDiv
{
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:red;
}​
```

## jQuery

```
$("#myDiv").mousemove(function (e) {
    console.log($(this).offset().left);
});
```

it says always "0". Where am I wrong?​

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
console.log("X Axis : " + e.pageX + " Y Axis : " + e.pageY);
```

This worked for me :-)

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).offset()` yields the position of the `#myDiv`, not of the mouse cursor. Use `e.clientX`.